# How to get first character-set of string in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('202500 135000', 1, 7) AS ExtractString;
SELECT SUBSTRING('37500 25000', 1, 5) AS ExtractString;
```

I want to get 202500 and 37500 without not adding removed characters (in eg: 7, 5). (ie. first string gp in columns).[sample-image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjL4L.png)
But, I don't know to get string in front of blank string "".
I have a little exp in sql. pls show me ans.

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(string_value, ' ', 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) instead

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('202500 135000', " ", 1) AS ExtractString;
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('37500 25000', " ", 1) AS ExtractString;
> ```
>
> ```
> | ExtractString |
> | :------------ |
> | 202500        |
>
> | ExtractString |
> | :------------ |
> | 37500         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ddc8be41d1f03b0a92a960bf150fd7f)*